# Why is a change always described like this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is $\Delta Y = Y_2 - Y_1$?

Why can't we write it as $\Delta Y = Y_1 - Y_2$?

or

$\Delta Y = Y_1 + Y_2$?

Why only the first equation?

Comment: Yesterday, I had $Y_1=3$ goats. Today, I have $Y_2=7$ goats. Over the last day, was my change in goats $Y_1 = Y_2 = -4$ goats or $Y_2 - Y_1 = 4$ goats? Which convention seems more useful for most applications?

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Now I get it, and also feel kinda dumb. Anyways, I hope your goats are doing good.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\Delta Y = Y_1+Y_2$ is not a *difference* (= common meaning of the symbol $\Delta) $, but the sum.
2. It is a convention to write $\Delta Y$ as $Y_2-Y_1$ as the change from $Y_1$ (the previous value) to the $Y_2$ (the next value), and not in the opposite direction.

   Probably it has a historic relation to physics and values in time $t_1$ and  $t_2$, where $t_1<t_2$. Then $\Delta Y$ was the change of a quantity $Y$ in time.